# How to Select a grid first row ,when press enter key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am Trying to select a kendo Grid Row .when press "ENTER"
key.

i tried below code:

```
("#grid").data("kendoGrid").table.focus();
```

this actually selects the table and focus to the cell.

But i want to select whole row.

Comment: Have you read the docs?  Do you know if it is at all possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Simply add this you can achieve this....try once..

```
 var selectFirstColumnOfKendoGrid = function () {
    var grid = $("#kendogrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var firstCell = grid.table.find("tr:first td:first");
    grid.current(firstCell);
    grid.table.focus();
    $('body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
}
```

in my app kendogrid is the id ...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :) The selector may be wrong because I don't know your HTML.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {

  if(e.which == 13) { //enter keycode

       $("#grid tr:first").focus();

   }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the first row of a grid is:

```
grid.select($("tr:first", grid.tbody));
```

But I do not understand when you want to press "enter"... but might be a little tricky since keyboard key presses are bound to default handlers.

Comment: Just hightlight the grid 1st row is enough sir.....Actually Using GetCall to receive a list from server..after that i need to search the data using one textbox value when i try to hit enter ..automatically select the 1st row ...

Comment: Then my answer is enough, isn't it?